# Python Dataframe : How to strip all values in a list in a column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, strip

I want to strip white spaces from all values in lists in the column 'Terms' in my dataframe:

```
df['Terms'] = df['Terms'].map(lambda x : x.strip())
```

This throws an error as the df['Terms'] type is list. Any help is appreciated.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

ANSWER:
I created a function and then apply it to the column of the dataframe:

```
def strip_element(my_list):
    return [x.strip() for x in my_list]

df['Terms']=df['Terms'].apply(strip_element)
```

Comment: `df['Terms'].str.strip()`?

Comment: How can i convert the column back to list type? df["Terms"]  = df["Terms"].apply(ast.literal_eval) throws an error: ValueError: malformed node or string: nan

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Then you can first do a `.fillna()`

Comment: `df['Terms'].replace('\s*,'',regex=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Rakesh, `df['Terms'] = df['Terms'].str.strip()` is the best solution, but since he already gave the solution, ypu can change `map` to `apply`:

```
df['Terms'] = df['Terms'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```